# Having problem with sign in

Tags: 12.04

I am new here and need help.  I have a Toshiba Satellite L505 Laptop with 320GBHDD 3GB DDR2 memory. I have a dual boot system and rarely use Windows 7 system on it and have Ubuntu 12.04 on the partition.  Everything was working wonderful and I saw that an Ubuntu upgrade was there last week and thought that I would get to doing that this week.  So, I go to boot up and everything is just fine and yet when I go to sign in some text very quick like flashes and then disappears and it goes back to the sign in.  So, over and again I do this so that I can get what it is saying in the second it displays.  This is what I was able to write down.

amed disabled: edit/etc/default/saned

So, I was able to do a Ctl+Alt+F1 and bring up terminal and then it said the following:

touch: cannot touch '/var/lib/update-notifier/hue-eol.started':no space left on device

run-parts: /etc/update-motd.d/95-hue-eol exited with return code 1

That is all of it.  I am not sure what to do or what it all means.  Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

*Can I increase space through the Windows 7 partition*

It is risky operation, especially when you are really almost out of space. You may lost or damage your data, but if you want to try it, use some LiveCD with GParted (or install gparted when on liveCD system).

Also, you can use

```
df -h
```

command in terminal to check available space in your system. Check

```
df -i
```

too. If any of output will be around 100% in USE column, you can post it.